# Limit character number in input

Tags: string, pascal

Is there a function to limit the number of characters a user can enter in the CLI to read in a variable?

I can limit the amount of characters a value can storage, so if i put `string[4]` and i enter `abcdef`, the variable stores just `abcd`.

I need to limit the number of characters a user can write. How can this be done?

This should be in standard Pascal, not Delphi.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, there is none.

Answer (score 1):

I would say read it character by character from CLI using `ReadKey`. Do this in a loop and break it if either the maximum number of characters have been reached or if the user presses return.

Comment: readkey is not standard pascal afaik, but a Borland extension